# Pentaho Kettle Database Connection - Connection object is closed

Tags: jdbc, sybase, pentaho, kettle

I've been working with Pentaho Kettle on an ETL solution and have ran into an error using Database Connection. I am trying to connect to a Sybase database using the Native(JDBC) access method in the Database Connection creator in Spoon. When I click the "Test" button in the Database Connection creator, Spoon tells me that the connection to the DB is OK. When I click "Explore" to view the database's schema, however, I get an error stating that the "Connection object is closed". This error also occurs when I use the "Table Input" step with a custom SQL statement which includes a JOIN. When I try to SELECT columns on JOINed tables, Spoon throws the "Connection object is closed" error again.

Any help on this would be appreciated. An online search suggested that the issue may be a JDBC driver issue or, possibly, a problem with how the database server is being ran. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some databases have a pretty elaborate authorization system. So, there may be a difference between just trying to connect (as in the Kettle connection setup test) and doing anything else, e.g. read a table or the meta data. Have you tried to do a simple SELECT using a standard interactive JDBC client?

Comment: @MarcusRickert Hmm I see. Let me elaborate a bit further. I can use Sybase Central (the database management system for Sybase) to explore the schema and run interactive SQL commands. I'm using the same credentials in spoon as I am to connect to the database in Sybase central. Further, there are custom SQL commands that DO work in the Table Input step in spoon. `SELECT column_name FROM table_name` works properly, as does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name`. Sample statements that don't work are `SELECT * FROM table_name` or `SELECT joined_field_name`

Comment: @MarcusRickert While thinking on this further, we're beginning to think it may be more valuable to find a way to connect via ODBC to the Sybase database. The problem is that Kettle throws an error regarding a missing ODBC driver. Would you happen to know how to include an ODBC driver? A few man-hours of work on this have yielded no results. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no clue how to do this.